# Does OneDrive support TLS 1.2?

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive file uploads failing when source URL is to a TLS 1.2 server

```
$ curl -L -H"Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN"  -H"Content-Type: application/json" -H"Prefer: respond-async" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children" -d'{
  "@microsoft.graph.sourceUrl": "https://tls-v1-2.badssl.com:1012/icons/icon-green.png",
  "name": "icon-green.png",
  "file": { }
}'
```

This returns a 202 Accepted, with a Location header containing a URL to track the upload. Following this returns:

```
{"operation":"DownloadUrl","status":"failed","statusDescription":"Unexpected response 'InternalServerError The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.' when downloading all content"}
```

With a TLS 1.0 Server (following the Location header)

```
$ curl -L -H"Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN"  -H"Content-Type: application/json" -H"Prefer: respond-async" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children" -d'{
  "@microsoft.graph.sourceUrl": "https://tls-v1-0.badssl.com:1010/icons/icon-red.png",
  "name": "icon-green.png",
  "file": { }
}'

{"operation":"DownloadUrl","percentageComplete":100.0,"resourceId":"6A071D3FEEC6C6B6!115","status":"completed","statusDescription":"URL was successfully downloaded to target"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should, but obviously it's not. We'll look into adding the support.

***Update:***

This has now been fixed - requests to download files on a TLS 1.2 endpoint should work.